# Floor function properties

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I need prove that $\forall n\geq 2$ $$2\lfloor\left(e-1\right)n!\rfloor=2n!\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!}$$
My idea: induction on $n$ but i can´t prove that: $$\lfloor\left(e-1\right)n!\rfloor=n\lfloor\left(e-1\right)\left(n-1\right)!\rfloor+1$$ $\forall n\geq2$

Comment: Possible hint: $e = + \dfrac{1}{0!}+ \dfrac{1}{1!}+ \dfrac{1}{2!}\cdots + \dfrac{1}{n!}\dots$

Comment: What's the point of the factor of $2$ on both sides of the equation?

Comment: none, we can skip on both sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $n\ge1.$ Since
$$(e-1)n!=n!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k!}=\frac{n!}{1!}+\frac{n!}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{n!}{n!}+\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{n!}{k!},$$
the identity
$$\lfloor(e-1)n!\rfloor=\frac{n!}{1!}+\frac{n!}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{n!}{n!}$$
follows from the fact that $\frac{n!}{1!}+\frac{n!}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{n!}{n!}$ is an integer, which is obvious, and the fact that $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{n!}{k!}\lt1,$ which we can see by comparing it with a geometric series:
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{n!}{k!}=\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\cdots$$$$\lt\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^3}+\cdots=\frac1n\le1.$$